# Integral Solutions for homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, homogeneous-equation

You are given three integers A, B, C, Let's call a triple of integers (a,b, c) interesting if it satisfies the following criteria:

1) $1 \leq a \leq A, 1 \leq b \leq B, 1 \leq c \leq C$

2) for any two real numbers x and y such that x != 0 and y != 0,

$ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2 > x^2 + y^2$ holds.

Problem: find number of triples $(a,b,c)$

I tried this problem but was unable to get the desired answer. Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: The key point is to divide the equation by $y^2$ and introduce $t=\frac{x}{y}$. This will get you a concrete formula using the fact that a quadratic function of $t$ is non-negative if and only if $\Delta \leq0$.

Comment: after solving Δ ≤ 0, the eqn becomes 4b^2 - 4b - 4ac + 4a + 1 ≤ 0.